# Performance Problem : PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, query-performance, plsql

```
SELECT
  NULL AS TRX_NUMBER ,
  NULL AS CUSTOMER_TRX_ID ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.DOCENTRY AS DOCENTRY ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.LINENUM AS LINENUM ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.ITEMCODE AS ITEMCODE ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.U_ALTDESC AS U_ALTDESC ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.PRICE AS PRICE ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.QUANTITY AS QUANTITY ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.LINETOTAL AS LINETOTAL ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.TAXSTATUS AS TAXSTATUS ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.TAX AS TAX ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.WHSCODE AS WHSCODE ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.U_WP AS U_WP ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.U_CASENUM AS U_CASENUM ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.U_FACILITY AS U_FACILITY ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.U_OPENED AS U_OPENED ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.U_CLOSED AS U_CLOSED ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.U_CONTACTPERSON AS U_CONTACTPERSON ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.LINETYPE AS LINETYPE ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.VISORDER AS VISORDER ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1."DATECREATEPORTAL" AS DATECREATEPORTAL ,
  NULL AS DATEMODIFYPORTAL ,
  NULL AS HDR_UPDATEDATE ,
  NULL AS LINE_UPDATEDATE ,
  NULL AS INV_CURR_CODE ,
  NULL AS HDR_ETL_UPDATE_DT ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.LINE_ETL_UPDATE_DT AS LINE_ETL_UPDATE_DT ,
  NULL AS WO_ETL_UPDATE_DT ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.ITEM_DESC AS ITEM_DESC ,
  VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.SOURCEID AS SOURCEID  
FROM
  ODS.VW_SAP_MPP_INV1 VW_SAP_MPP_INV1
WHERE
  (VW_SAP_MPP_INV1.LINE_ETL_UPDATE_DT >= TO_DATE(SUBSTR('2022-07-26 15:35:19.0',0,19),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

> ```
>  The `View` is a simple select from a `table`
> ```
>
> It fetch 50 rows within `0.50 sec`(without the "WHERE" condition)
> With `"WHERE" condition` it takes `80 seconds.`

Please suggest on how to improve this performance.[image: EXPLAIN PLAN]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a simple select from a table. You have 2 tables with a join.

Fetching the first 50 rows randomly without a condition is not the same as fetching the first 50 rows specified by conditions.

1. The datatypes of columns used for join do not match, indicated by SYS_OP_C2C internal conversion function in plan. This should be fixed because it will never be optimal like this.
2. Even though you use Exadata (indicated by STORAGE FULL), the storage indexes are not some kind of magic that can replace standard indexes in all scenarios. An index may help here, but we do not know your tables, the amount and distribution of data. Try creating an index on SAP_INV1(ETL_UPDATE_DT), or if such index exists, check the statistics to see why it is not used.
3. Finally, parallel query may be an unnecessary overhead depending on the amount of data, which again, we do not know.

Comment: hi Papp , thank you for your insights, Your suggestion on creating index on etl_update_dt worked very well was getting results in less than a second. Can you please explain your third point.